# variables substation of a curve $|x|+|y|=2$

Tags: calculus

In order to solve an integral over the curve $$|x|+|y|=2$$ it is easier to use a variables substation to $w=x-y$ and $u=x+y$ where $|J|=2$ so the overall integral need to be multiple by $\frac{1}{2}$.

How do I find the limit of integration under the new variables?

Comment: Not sure what $J$ is.  In any case:  the figure in question is a square.  In particular, it is piecewise linear.  Easiest, I'd think, to just integrate over each of the four linear segments separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$|x|+|y|=2$. Min value of $|x| =$ min value of $|y| = 0$

So for $x = 0$, you have two points $(0,\pm2)$ and similarly for $y = 0$, you have two points $(\pm2,0)$.

You can see this is a square with diagonal length $4$ unit and side length $2\sqrt2$.

Equations of $4$ lines -

$x + y \pm 2 = 0$ and $x - y \pm 2 = 0$

You can integrate over each linear segment.